# Save file info for processing not seen by user in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am working on a project in Eclipse wherein I need to save extra information attached with file and some derived from files such that user can't see them directly. For e.g., after loading file, some process is done on that file and I need to save result of that process such that I can use it later on.

The information that I need to store can be long strings and in form of bytes too.

Is there any feature in Eclipse using which I can do this task?

*I am using Eclipse 4.5.2*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save strings using the `setPersistentProperty` and `getPersistentProperty` methods of `IFile`.

You can also save any sort of data you want in the 'state location' for your plugin.

Get the state location with:

```
Bundle bundle = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(getClass());

IPath location = Platform.getStateLocation(bundle);
```

This is a directory in the workspace .metadata.